# ScrollBarInfo isn't Working for me

Tags: c#, winforms

I searched for all the information I could possibly find, and looked at the few examples I found, and I figured I was doing every thing right, but the results are disappointing.
I am at my last leg of accomplishing my goal. Basically, all I need to do now, is find out when the scroll bar has reached the top, or come to a stop.

First I made sure that I am dealing with the correct window.
Once I locate the window, I then try to get the information.

```
// get scrollbar info
SCROLLINFO scrollinfo = new SCROLLINFO();
scrollinfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(scrollinfo);
scrollinfo.fMask = SIF_ALL; // Get all the scroll bar information.
bool horBar = GetScrollInfo1(windowHandle, SB_HORZ, out scrollinfo);
Console.WriteLine(horBar);
bool vertBar = GetScrollInfo1(windowHandle, SB_VERT, out scrollinfo);
Console.WriteLine(vertBar);
Console.WriteLine(scrollinfo.nPage + ", " + scrollinfo.nPos);
```

Both return False, and 0.

```
// Get current scroller position
Orientation scriptWinSBar = Orientation.Vertical;
GetScrollPos(windowHandle, scriptWinSBar);
```

Here is the only place I got a non zero. This returns 1, and rightly so, because the window does not contain a horizontal bar (which returned a zero).

```
if ((int)scriptWinSBar > 0)
{
      scrollinfo.fMask = SIF_POS;
      GetScrollInfo1(windowHandle, SB_VERT, out scrollinfo);
      Console.WriteLine("pos; " + scrollinfo.nPos.ToString());

      scrollinfo.fMask = SIF_RANGE;
      GetScrollInfo1(windowHandle, SB_VERT, out scrollinfo);
      Console.WriteLine("min,max; " + scrollinfo.nMin.ToString() + ", " + scrollinfo.nMax.ToString());
 }
 Console.WriteLine("  scriptWinSBar : " + (int)scriptWinSBar);
```

Here all the results are zero, 
pos; 0
min,max; 0, 0
  scriptWinSBar : 1

...although the scroll bar is at or near the bottom.
I am not sure if I am doing wrong, or is there something I am not doing.
Could someone help me get this right please. Or possibly provide an example on how I can get the scroll bar's position, or know if it is scrolling or has stopped scrolling? Thanks.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this. However, I am trying to get the scroll bar info from a windows process.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me in c++ for using scroll bars inside of a dialog box. Using SCROLLINFO versus SCROLLBARINFO was a little tricky. Using GetScrollInfo(...) only seemed to work properly after setting up the min/max

```
int ret = 0;

SCROLLBARINFO sbar_info = { 0 };
sbar_info.cbSize = sizeof(sbar_info);
        
if (GetScrollBarInfo(slider10_hwnd, OBJID_CLIENT, &sbar_info))
{
    slider10_is_sbar = true;

    //SAFECOM::Display_Message(TEXT("slider10 Is a Scroll Bar"));

    // setup min/max
    SCROLLINFO s_info = { 0 };
    s_info.cbSize = sizeof(s_info);
    s_info.fMask = SIF_ALL;
    s_info.nMin = ctrl_min;
    s_info.nMax = ctrl_max;
    s_info.nPos = ctrl_cur;

    ret = SetScrollInfo(slider10_hwnd, SB_CTL, &s_info, TRUE);
       
}
else
{
    slider10_is_sbar = false;

    //SAFECOM::Display_Message(TEXT("slider10 Is Not a Scroll Bar"));
}
```

Inside of my dialog_proc this is how I get the scroll info.

```
WM_HSCROLL:
{
   WORD code = LOWORD(wParam);
   WORD id   = HIWORD(wParam);
   HWND slider10_hwnd = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_SLIDER10);
   bool match10 = false;
   
   match10 = (slider10_hwnd == (HWND)lParam);

   if (slider10_hwnd && slider10_is_sbar && match10)
   {
       if (code == SB_LINELEFT)  { OnSlider10_Button_Left();  return TRUE; }
       if (code == SB_LINERIGHT) { OnSlider10_Button_Right(); return TRUE; }
     
       if ((code == SB_THUMBTRACK) || (code == SB_THUMBPOSITION))
       {
           // Get the current position where the mouse has dragged it  
           SCROLLINFO s_info = { 0 };
           s_info.cbSize = sizeof(s_info);
           s_info.fMask = SIF_POS;

           if (GetScrollInfo(slider10_hwnd, SB_CTL, &s_info))
           {
              s_info.nPos = s_info.nTrackPos;
        
              // move the thumb to the mouse location and redraw
              // otherwise it will bounce back to the previous position after releasing the mouse button
              SetScrollInfo(slider10_hwnd, SB_CTL, &s_info, TRUE);

              OnSlider10_Moved(s_info.nPos);
           }
       }      

       return TRUE;
   }

} break;
```